# Paginating results from model function

Tags: cakephp, pagination

For CakePhp 2.5

I have the following search function in my Controller.

```
 public function search($query = null, $lim = null)
{
    $tokens = explode(" ", $query);
         $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Customer.site_id LIKE' => '%' . $this->viewVars['shopId'],
                        'CONCAT(Customer.first_name," ",Customer.last_name," ",Customer.organisation) LIKE' => '%' . implode(' ', $tokens) . '%'
                    ),
                    'limit' => $lim
                );
         $this->set('customers', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

This works fine, and gets the results i want.

However, its been suggested to me that I should put these search functions in my model. I can easily do this, and have done so similar as follows in my model:

```
 public function getActiveTasks($id){
        return $this->Task->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Task.customer_id' => $id,
                'Task.status' => 0
            ),
            'order' => array('Task.due_date ASC'),
            'recursive' => -1,
        ));
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that I cannot (or don't know how to) use Paginator with custom searches. Is there a way to paginate results from custom functions?

ie, can I do the following:

```
 public function CustomModelSearch($query = null, $lim = null)
{
    return $this->Task->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Customer.site_id LIKE' => '%' . $this->viewVars['shopId'],
            'CONCAT(Customer.first_name," ",Customer.last_name," ",Customer.organisation) LIKE' => '%' . implode(' ', $tokens) . '%'
        ),
        'limit' => $lim
    ));
}
```

and then in the controller call

```
$results = $this->Model->CustomModelSearch($query, $lim);
$this->set('results',$this->Paginate($results));
```

I cannot find a way to pass results into the paginator to render paged results to the view, unless I use it via the controller as per the first piece of code, which i've been told isn't good MVC principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom pagination you have two options:

- Create a [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) with a `paginate` and `paginateCount` funtions

  // paginate and paginateCount implemented on a behavior.
  public function paginate(Model $model, $conditions, $fields, $order, $limit,
      $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {
      // method content
  }

  public function paginateCount(Model $model, $conditions = null, $recursive = 0,
      $extra = array()) {
      // method body
  }
- or create a [custom find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-custom-find) and set `Paginator` to use that find.

Answer (score 0):

good to understand but the truth should tell me that bug hits you in what you're doing.

The function  in the model of "Task" you should not put `$this->task->find`just`$this->find` that if you are in the model  not need specify which model you are using, ou only need to do this in the controller.

model/Task.php:

```
public function CustomModelSearch($query = null, $lim = null)
{
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Customer.site_id LIKE' => '%' . $this->viewVars['shopId'],
            'CONCAT(Customer.first_name," ",Customer.last_name," ",Customer.organisation) LIKE' => '%' . implode(' ', $tokens) . '%'
        ),
        'limit' => $lim
    ));
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this. The function posted is just an example to illustrate my point.

Comment: put your question explain your problem and that error give to you and your code wihtout examples